# What's the proper pattern for local $scope functions in controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller I have several local functions that are related to the $scope. They seem to get out of control now as that number increases. What is the proper pattern to structure these local controller functions?

For example,

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.func1 = function() {
        // do something with $scope
    }
    $scope.func2 = function() {
        // do something with $scope
    }
    $scope.func3 = function() {
        // do something with $scope
    }

    // ... controller code here ...
}
```

Is there a good way to make these local func1, func2, func3 more manageable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define your controller as a class, and use the prototype to add functionnality :

```
var myController = function($scope){
  var _this = this;

  $scope.func1= function(){
    _this.func1();
  };
};

myController.prototype.func1 = function(){
  // do something here
};

app.controller('myController', myController);
```

This way you will avoid "scope soup". There is a great article about it [here](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html)

Note that you could also avoid $scope using the "as" keyword:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
   <input ng-click="ctrl.func1()">
</div>

var myController = function(){
    this.someVar = "A value";
};
myController.prototype.func1 = function(){
   // do something here
};
```

Comment: Can't u just call ng-click="func1()"

Comment: You can if you are using $scope.
If you want to get rid of it with the "Controller As" syntax, you will have to call it with ctrl.func1().
Making clear where a property comes from can be really useful. But you can use whatever syntax you like.

Comment: Does this really solve the problem or just move it around? You still have to have a bunch of functions hanging off the $scope, even if they  all just call _this.funcx(). In fact, one could argue that this is a worse solution because it makes things more complicated by adding another class.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my approach:

```
function myController($scope) {

     $scope.func1 = func1;
     $scope.func2 = func2;


    func1 = function() {

    }
    func2 = function(x) {
        // do something with x
    }
}
```

And when I call func2 I give it $scope.whatever I need, that way I keep my $scope out of my func body.